# What is the parameter passed to the callback function of a promise in this example?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm following an example online:

```
const jeffBuysCake3 = cakeType => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(()=> {
      if (cakeType
 === 'black forest') {
        resolve('black forest cake!') //Callback function
      } else {
        reject('No cake ') //Callback function
      }
    }, 1000)
  })
}

console.log(jeffBuysCake3('black forest').then(cake => console.log(cake)).catch(nocake => console.log(nocake)))
```

This returns `black forest cake!`

The part I don't understand is `cake => console.log(cake)`

What is `cake` in this example?

I understand that passing 'black forest' represents the parameter `cakeType`.

However It's not clear to me what 'cake' is.

Does `cake` = `resolve`?

Comment: To understand the code above you would need to understand what and how async calls and promise works in JavaScript. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise for more information

Comment: The value that you resolve the promise with (ie: `'black forest cake!'` in `resolve('black forest cake!')`) will be the value that you get as the first argument of the callback to `.then()` (ie: the value of `cake`)

Answer (score 2):

Cake means the result of the successfully called promise, in this example they probably want to mean the cake result, and the cake result is a "black forest".

You could write it like this

```
jeffBuysCake3('black forest')
.then(result => console.log(result))
.catch(error => console.log(error))
```

and the result is going to be "black forest cake",
if the promise function was like this

```
const jeffBuysCake3 = cakeType => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(()=> {
      if (cakeType
 === 'black forest') {
        resolve('Strawberry cake !') //Callback function
      } else {
        reject('No cake for you today') //Callback function
      }
    }, 1000)
  })
}
```

the result is going to be "Strawberry Cake !", while if there was an error it would print out "No cake for you today".

In case you don't know how promises work, when we supply `.then` it means if the promise resolved (successfully) then give me back the result. If it couldn't be resolved, then catch the error which then we use `.catch`.